# Busco saber que SPs utilizan un indice en especifico en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, indices, sql-server-2019

cree un índice el cual en menos de 24 horas ya tiene más de 50,000 búsquedas, pero necesito saber que sps lo consumen ya que la tabla al que pertenece el índice es la más usada de la base de datos. Esto lo requiero para no estar teniendo que analizar el plan de ejecución uno por uno de los sps que me devuelve el sp_depends.

Probe las soluciones que recomiendan en este post, pero no es lo que necesito:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247713/how-to-find-what-stored-procedures-are-using-what-indexes

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la liga que compartes vienen un par de soluciones que usan los planes almacenados en cache y son los que utilizan `sys.dm_exec_query_plan`. Una versión sencilla puede ser algo así.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME( object_id),
       query_plan 
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats s
cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(s.plan_handle) as p 
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
AND CAST( p.query_plan AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE N'%NombreDelIndice%'
```

Aunque eso puede traer información incompleta ya que el cache es constantemente eliminado para hacer espacio o tener información actualizada.

Otra opción que tienes es activar Query Store (todos deberían de tenerla activada como herramienta para analizar problemas). Teniendo Query Store funcionando, puedes buscar en sus vistas que tienen información un poco más permanente.

```
SELECT  
        DB_NAME() dbname, 
        MIN( CAST( switchoffset (s.last_execution_time, '-05:00') AS datetime)) AS fecha,
        MAX( CAST( switchoffset (s.last_execution_time, '-05:00') AS datetime)) AS fecha,
        t.query_sql_text, 
        q.query_id, 
        o.name AS objeto
        --,CONVERT( XML, p.query_plan) AS plan
FROM sys.query_store_query_text             AS t
JOIN sys.query_store_query                  AS q ON t.query_text_id = q.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan                   AS p ON q.query_id      = p.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats          AS s ON p.plan_id       = s.plan_id
LEFT JOIN sys.objects                       AS o ON q.object_id     = o.object_id
WHERE p.query_plan LIKE '%NombreDelIndice%'
GROUP BY t.query_sql_text, 
        q.query_id, 
        o.name
        --,p.query_plan
```

Si quieres obtener el plan de ejecución, puedes descomentar las columnas. Sin embargo, eso puede generar filas "repetidas" puesto que los planes pueden variar para una misma consulta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis, con esa consulta entre otras cosas encontre el sp al cual el indice los impacto en un 99%, muchas gracias.